# Migrating rows to a new table and then deleting them

Tags: php, mysql, database, migration, rows

I have a large database of products and everyday I wish to run a script that moves rows with active = '1' into a new table and deletes the original row.

But I can't seem to find the appropriate Mysql command to accomplish the migration.

It would be great if someone could shed some light on the situation.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to complete this with the following

```
CREATE TABLE NewTable LIKE OldTable;

INSERT INTO NewTable 
SELECT * FROM OldTable WHERE Active = 1;

DELETE FROM OldTable WHERE Active = 1;
```

Just as curiosity, what is the point of doing this?  If you're worried about the fuzzy rows you could do the delete as follows

```
DELETE OldTab FROM OlTable AS OldTab
INNER JOIN NewTable AS NewTab
ON OldTab.ID = NewTab.ID
```

Comment: watch out for the fuzzy edge...  new rows may be inserted with active=1 in between these two statements - giving undesired results.

Comment: Yeah, if you're worried about that you can lock the table for the duration of the insert and delete.  Although I sense from the question that the old table is being discarded.

Answer (score 0):

without any details, here is what you will do:

create an INSERT statement to the new table AS SELECT from the old table WHERE active = 1.

create a DELETE statement that deletes from the first table any rows it finds in the second table.

commit;

Comment: @Clodoaldo - would you give it a +2 if Randy typed the code for the OP ;)